# Angular2 one component and multiple routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my web application I have one component, that got array with `text-data` to display. The array, is dynamically changing according to button(that decide what data stored in variable send to array, we are choosing from three options) was selected.

I want to make routing, that will change according to sent data to array. Can somebody tell how to do routing to this type situation?

Update:

Gallery components gets 3 array's with female/male/premium models data from my service. We decide what model's type to show in our navigation. According to chose I want to have route '/models', /model, '/premium .

Gallery.component.html

```
<div class="demonstration__navigation">
    <nav class="navigation">
        <button 
            class="button" 
            (click)="onChangeModelsTeamClick('female')"
        >
            MODELKI
        </button><!--
     --><button 
            class="button"
            (click)="onChangeModelsTeamClick('male')"
        >
            MODELE
        </button><!--
     --><button 
            class="button"
            (click)="onChangeModelsTeamClick('premium')"
        >
            PREMIUM
        </button>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="demonstration__slider">
   <app-teamDemonstration 
        [models]="getChosenModels()"
        (chosenModel)="chosenModel=$event"
    >
    </app-teamDemonstration>
</div>
```

Gallery.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-gallery',
    templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.scss'],
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

    femaleModels: Model[];
    maleModels: Model[];
    premiumModels: Model[];
    chosenModels: string; 

    constructor(private _modelsService: ModelsService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this._modelsService
            .getFemaleModels()
            .subscribe( responseFemaleModelsData => this.femaleModels = responseFemaleModelsData );
        this._modelsService
            .getMaleModels()
            .subscribe( responseMaleModelsData => this.maleModels = responseMaleModelsData );
        this._modelsService
            .getPremiumModels()
            .subscribe( responsePremiumModelsData => this.premiumModels = responsePremiumModelsData );

        this.chosenModels = this._modelsService.getchosenModels();
        this._modelsService._chosenModelsUpdate.subscribe(
            (chosenModels) => {
                this.chosenModels = this._modelsService.getchosenModels();
            }
        );        
    }

    onChangeModelsTeamClick(value: string) {
        this._modelsService.setchosenModels(value);
    }
    getChosenModels() {
        switch(this.chosenModels) {
            case 'female': return this.femaleModels;        
            case 'male': return this.maleModels;     
            case 'premium': return this.premiumModels;         
            default : return this.femaleModels;         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and what have you tried so far?

Comment: show us your project structure for routing also what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Legendarny: First try to break your pen on paper you will get the answer.

Comment: I updated my post.